# IDEA/Eclipse class finder like GWT widget with keyboard handling

Tags: gwt, keyboard-shortcuts

Brief:
I have a GWT TextBox and CellList. I would like the up/down keys to do keyboard selection in the CellList while focus is still in the Textbox (search filter). How do I do that?

Details:
Right now, if I focus the celllist, it behaves as I want, however, I don't want to have to leave the search field to select an element with the up/down keys. The up/down keys seem to have a behavior I don't need in the Textbox (move to beginning/end of text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually rather easy: use a [`SuggestBox`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.html) and provide your own [`SuggestionDisplay`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.SuggestionDisplay.html), which can be a `CellList` or `Menu` widget (or whatever) sitting anywhere you want it.

The `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` opens a `Menu` in a `PopupPanel`, but that's just the default implementation. If you ever used Google Wave, what you're asking for looks a lot like the person chooser when inviting people to your waves, and it was a `SuggestBox` AFAICT.